# How to mock Jax Rs 2.0 Rest Client Response?

Tags: java, jersey, mockito, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

How can I mock Jax RS Client using Mockito?

```
  Foo expected = new Foo();

  when(restClient.target(anyString())
            .path(anyString()) //Got NPE here
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .post(Entity.entity(expected, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .readEntity(Foo.class)
    ).thenReturn(expected);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to mock every method call:

```
when(restClient.target(anyString()).thenReturn(...)
when(target.path(anyString()).thenReturn(...)
...
```

I am not aware what restClient returns... maybe it is just returning the restClient?

Comment: Please complete the answer with proper return.

Comment: In order to do this I need to know what "target", "path", "request", "post" and "readEnity" methods are returning.

Comment: any() could do.

Comment: Not really. You have to return the object that will be used afterwards for the call of the next method. If you are using some generic restClient can you share it?